# Rails f.check_box set checked/unchecked values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, helper

so I got a form helper in rails with a checkbox;
I want that checkbox to have values as "thatvalue" or "thisvalue" when checked or unchecked;
I haven't found anywhere how to set this up with

```
f.check_box :field
```

I found something like that

```
<%= form.check_box :field, {}, "thisvalue", "thatvalue"  %>
```

but it doesn't work, because I also set :class and :style inside my tag, so having something like

```
<%= form.check_box :field, {}, "thisvalue", "thatvalue", :class => "checkbox", :style => "display:none;" %>
```

errors and tells me wrong number of arguments (5 for 4)

so right now I have to "hack" it in my controller, and set my field depending on if my checkbox is 0 or 1... which is pretty bad.

any idea?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

ok nevermind, I misunderstood the "options" field...

the answer is simply

```
<%= f.check_box :field, {:class => "myclass", :style => "mystyle"}, "checked-value", "unchecked-value" %>
```

and it works perfectly :)