# How to get a value from check box in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting Boolean value output.

```
    **_form.html.erb**


    <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  Gender:<br>  <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "Male")%>
    <%= f.label(:gender_option1, "Male") %><br />
     <%= f.radio_button(:gender, "Female")%>
    <%= f.label(:gender_option2, "Female") %>
   </div>
  <div class="field">
    Payment:<br>
    <%= f.check_box(:paymentmode )%>
    <%= f.label :Debitcard %>
    <%= f.check_box :paymentmode %>
    <%= f.label :Creditcard %>
    <%= f.check_box :paymentmode %>
    <%= f.label :cashondelivery %>

   <br />


  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>

    **Index.html.erb**

        <tr>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= user.gender %></td>
        <td>$<%= user.price %></td>
        <td><%= user.paymentmode %></td>
        </tr>
```

I want to get the value of check box i.e. debit card or credit card or cash on delivery. I am getting output as below:

```
Name: xyz Email: xyz@gmail.com gender:Male price:$100 payment mode : 0
```

I need payment mode like debit or credit or cod in string format. I want payment mode : `Cashondelivery/credit/debit.`

Comment: Check the [API Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box). You can always pass **checked_value** to something you want to

Comment: ya  i used abhi but it's showing only boolean value either 0 or 1. But i need payment mode is either credit / debit / cashondeliver

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573508/rails-f-check-box-set-checked-unchecked-values

Comment: I don't see you are using it. I can see you use like `f.check_box(:paymentmode )`, but you have to use it as mentioned in docs or pointed by @elsapet

Comment: undefined method `merge' for "unchecked-value":String. It's says like this

Comment: I would say use collection_select instead 

Comment: @kirankumar could you please show what your `<%= f.check_box ( ... ) %>` looks like now?

Answer (score 0):

Use [radio buttons](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) just like you are using for male or female. They are mutually exclusive. 

    `<%= f.radio_button(:paymentmode, "debit")%>
    <%= f.label(:debitcard, "Debit Card") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:paymentmode, "credit")%>
    <%= f.label(:dreditcard, "Credit Card") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:paymentmode, "Cash")%>
    <%= f.label(:cash, "Cash on delivery") %>`